# Run Win 16-bit Application in Wine

Tags: windows, wine, xubuntu

Xubuntu 12.04. HP Compaq nc8430. 2 GB RAM. Wine 1.4.

I'm trying to run Castle of the Winds, an old 16-bit Windows application, in Wine. I've put the application in .wine/drive_c. I've added it as an application in Wine, and I've tried setting the Windows version to 3.1, and I've also tried Win XP. Each time I try to run the app, Xubuntu freezes. I can do a Ctl-Alt-F4, and then a Ctl-Alt-Del to reboot. This application is not a DOS application, so I don't think DOSbox will help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Updated answer for 2020-2021

Here are the steps to run this 16-bit App:

1. `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`
2. `wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key`
3. `sudo apt-key add winehq.key`
4. `sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'` I am using 20.04, but change focal to groovy if you are using 20.10.
5. `sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-devel` Change winehq-devel to winehq-stable if you would like to use the stable version instead
6. Run `winecfg` once so it installs all required packages to work correctly like gecko. In some cases as mentioned below, it would be needed to set the Windows version to XP.
7. Visit the Castle in the Wind folder. For me it showed both versions inside of it:

[image]

8. Go to Castle1 for example and on the terminal type `wine CASTLE1.EXE` to begin

[image]

For Castle2, type `wine CASTLE2.EXE` in the terminal, inside this folder to play it

[image]

**NOTES**

- I am playing in Ubuntu 20.04
- I did not install any additional packages via winetricks.
- There are less steps to do now with the latest wine version, which at this time is Wine 6.0-rc3
- There was no need to changing the Window version inside winecfg since it worked with Windows XP, 7, 8 and 10 (In my case). The default one was windows 7, which is the one used for this test. But as noted by Adrian, he needed Windows XP (Like the previous version of this answer) to make it work.

Comment: Ok, the error stream (I figured the stdout was uninteresting) from the sudo apt-get update command is here: http://pastebin.com/u8jxKTUq.

Comment: Here is the result of the locate \*wine\* command: http://pastebin.com/W17iJxFC.

Comment: For the BADSIG see http://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors

Comment: For the wine files with locate I would first do a apt-get purge then continue with something similar to this http://askubuntu.com/questions/86702/will-this-find-and-delete-command-work-with-the-asterisk-even-with-quotes to delete all wine files. The files located inside your home folder are never deleted byt apt-get purge for safety reasons. I would delete the "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/wine/" folder before doing this. Save you some time there. Before doing this however, you need to first remove the wine PPA since it also appears on that locate list.

Comment: I should also mention your problems are already outside the scope of running a 16 bit game on wine. You have other issues so I recommend searching in Askubuntu for each case. The BADSIG was one. The additional packages in /var/lig/dpkg and /var/cache/apt showed that you tried several versions, this means you need to do a cleanup using apt-get / aptitude first before installing wine again. So please search askubuntu for any other issues that are not related to 16 bit on wine since all of this issues have already been mentioned.

Comment: I'm happy to report that this basic procedure still works for Linux Mint Xfce 18.3, 64-bit.

Comment: Happen to have any idea which packages would be required for the spell animations to show up? It's a small point, but it would add to the game.

Comment: Unfortunately, this procedure does NOT seem to work for Linux Mint 19. I get `Cannot add PPA: ''This PPA does not support bionic''.` Is there an update?

Comment: Also tried it with Wine1.6, but no joy. It's complaining about not supporting 64-bit applications.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Why are you trying it with 1.6 when there is 3.x (either stable 3.0.3 or 3.17 at the time of this writing) and there already a guide for the correct installation at https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine/316029 ?

Comment: Well, that might work. The issue is that I'm running a VERY old application here (more than two decades), and I'm not at all sure Wine 3.x is going to be THAT backwards compatible.

Comment: @adriankeister which app is that?

Comment: The one in the question: Castle of the Winds.

Comment: Well, kudos to @LuisAlvarado: the latest version of Wine with as many of the packages listed above installed, works. It even works better than before, on account of the spell animations working (they didn't before). So, excellent!

Comment: One comment: quite a few of these packages have very buggy installations; I did find `icodecs` to fail spectacularly - recommend skipping that one.

Comment: Trying this on Pop!_OS 20.04 with no joy. In fact, it freezes my machine regularly and repeatedly. There are several packages you have listed there that are no longer listed in my winetricks, such as mono210, wsh56vb, and xact_june2010. I also have several packages listed that you don't: remove_mono, w_workaround_wine_bug-24013, fontfix, winxp, iertutil, and w_workaround_wine_bug-30718. Do you know if any of these differences could be causing the problem?

Comment: For that matter, an updated answer for 2020 starting from scratch would be super, but I don't know if you have the time.

Comment: Thank you @AdrianKeister so basically this needs an update. Let me see what I can do.

Comment: Have you had any ideas lately? I realize this is low priority, but as you can see, lots of people have been interested in this question. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hi @AdrianKeister sorry for not working on this (kids, work, 2020 stuff). Can you put here a list of apps you wish to test or email me at luisalvarado@ubuntu.com so we can work on this and update the answer for a 2020 version.

Comment: It's still just the Castle of the Winds game. Great game!

Comment: Hi @AdrianKeister I have updated answer and tested what seems like 2 versions of the game. I uploaded the images to show you and the exact steps.

Comment: Excellent! Only one thing: I had to config Wine to use Windows XP instead of the default Windows 7, and then it ran! Many thanks!

Comment: @AdrianKeister thank you! I was trying to run a 16bit app in Wine and your comment saved me!  You should create an answer, so I can upvote it! Happy holidays man